# uncomment xml tags on centOS 7.x

Tags: linux, xml, sed, centos

Is there a command (using sed or any other tool) to remove XML comment (which has a comment string also) on some XML tags? I am using centos 7.4 and 7.9. The XML structure is like this:

```xml
<root>
  <!-- Some string here to inform 
    <SomeTagHere />
    <SomeTagHere2> </SomeTagHere2>
  -->
</root>
```

I tried many different sed commands but none of them worked and I couldn't find a proper regex for this. What I want to is release tags inside comment like this:

```xml
<root>
  <SomeTagHere />
  <SomeTagHere2> </SomeTagHere2>
</root>
```

Comment: You really want to use an XML-aware tool for this, not plain regular expressions. If you insist on using `sed`, please show us what you searched for and what you tried before asking here; this is a relatively common question and probably a duplicate of an existing question if you manage to edit it into shape.

Comment: Hi @tripleee, so far I searched other similar issues in stack overflow but they are usually does not have any information string after '<!--' and have only one tag between '<!--' and '-->'. I tried answers in questions including 'sed' and 'perl' solutions. None of them worked so far, or i couldn't write a proper regex for this situation. That's another point im trying to figure out.

Comment: The trouble with `sed` is it can't easily look ahead at the following lines. `perl -000 -pe 's/<!--[^\n]*(.*?)-->/$1/gs'` probably does roughly what you are asking if I can guess correctly what you want, but comes with all the usual caveats about trying to use plain string matching and ignoring the structure of XML.

Comment: For example, it will not understand that `<a href="/" title="<!-- not a comment -->">/</a>` is not a comment, even though text inside a quoted string should be ignored by a proper parser.

Comment: Just an approach: You can use [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) to convert XML to YAML with comments (`yq --input-format xml file.xml`),
process the YAML und convert it back to XML (`yq --output-format xml file.xml`).
The function [from_xml](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/encode-decode) should help solving your task.
As long as this interesting question is closed, I cannot show you how to do it

Comment: Does it have to be a solution with `sed` or is another command line tool ok that solves the task? I think it is almost impossible to solve this problem properly with `sed` because it is not sensitive to context.

Comment: hi @jpseng, any tool that I can install and use in CentOS 7.x is also okay